# Windows 10 constant graphics driver crashing for no apparent reason

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, crash, event-log, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently bought asus gtx 750 oc card, installed it with its driver on windows 7 and it worked fine. Indidntnuse it too long but longer than I could run it on windows 10 without a problem. http://m.ebuyer.com/623632 that's the card.

I have now done a fresh install of windows 10, and other than my wireless adapter driver this was the only other thing I installed. The driver for the card.

I have updated to the latest driver available Also.

After some time of the pc being logged in (between 5-15 minutes) the displays lose signal and never regain signal, forcing me to turn the pc off.

Upon checking the event log, there is a warning repeating every 4 seconds. It states that nvlddmkm.exe recovered from a crash with event id 4101.

I have tried googling the problem. The first thing I did was go into power management settings and change the PCI express power management setting off. That didn't work. I then looked at some graphs of temperature etc before it crashes but everything seems mega low. 35 degrees on temp for example. Gpu usage at like 1 or 2%.

Other all I could think of was that perhaps the factory oc was a problem? So I installed gpu tweak, the oc tool that ships with it and set all clock values much lower. I also tried this separately via msi afterburner. No luck there either.

It crashes with nothing very intensive open. Firefox and settings panel, as an example.

When I try and launch final fantasy, that crashes it right away on demand also.

Things that might be worth mentioning:
I have 2 monitors. One via vga (1920x1080) and another which is on the hdmi port, using a hdmi to vga converter. Screen size is a smaller 4:3 display. This setup was also used whilst on win 7.

Also whilst installing the card I found no 6 pin slot or anything for me to attach power from the psu. I assumed it must take all its power from the mobo

The psu is 850w and should be easily overkill for the needs. The only hardware change has been the card, which replaced 2 9800 gtxs in sli before it.

I don't know what else I could try to get it to not crash now...

Comment: Your GPU does indeed draw all its power from the PCIe slot. What exact driver version are you running? People often think they are installing the latest certified version, but aren't.

Comment: I first installed the driver that ships with the card on the cd, then updated using GeForce program thing. I can't remember the exact driver version number but it's around 355 I believe? Can give the exact number when infer home tonight. The GeForce program checked for more recent versions after it updated and found nothing newer.

Comment: To clarify - I am home now and yes, the driver version was 355.60 - The latest currently released.

Comment: try the last driver before the 29th July [WIn10 day!]; there were 2 WIn10 drivers rushed out within a few days, 353.62 then 355.60 Some people have had more luck going back to the one before that, 353.30. http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us

Comment: No luck with older drivers either unfortunately :-(

Comment: I have updated my bios, reinstalled fresh windows 10 and still no luck. Have exhausted all advice that GeForce support were able to give, they have directed me to contact Microsoft directly :-/